# Question about optimal play in UNO.

Tags: game-theory, card-games

This is a strange question that came up while playing the card game UNO. In some versions of the UNO there is a card, in which the player who plays it takes everyone's cards and redistributes them equally among all players. This leads to everyone having an equal number of cards, with some situations in which the player redistributing the cards has less cards (e.g. a 2 player game with odd cards, player 1 will end up with 1 fewer cards).

In a situation in which you are playing against one other player, you have one card left that happens to be the redistribute card, while you opponent has 10 cards left.

Is it optimal to play the redistribute card straight away or wait until your opponent has fewer cards?

Here is my thinking:

- Playing the card straight away means you both end up with 5 cards each, meaning you have decent odds to have playable cards, which leads to the game being less random.
- If you wait and play the card when your opponent has fewer cards, you increase the odds you don't have playable cards.

Sorry if this does not belong on this website.

Comment: While it would be possible to approach this question mathematically, it would be messy, and likely best approached by simulation. There is a [Board & Card Games forum](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) on StackExchange. It would almost certainly be better asked there.

Comment: I would add my intuitive thought on this. It depends a bit on the rules so I will do by cases. If I play that card, do I pick cards to redistribute or do I do it by random? If i pick them, I'd say, play when he has $10$, you will be able to pick more good cards. If I do it by random, whose turn is it after? I would assume, that whoever is on the turn if we have equal number of random cards has bigger chance of winning (and the fewer the cards, the bigger the chance). So if it's his turn, play when he has $10$ cards, and if it's you again, only then play when he has $2$ cards.